# Multiple Dynamic Canvas Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have some code dynamically generating canvas elements from images using jquery and want to apply a single drawing context to each and all of these elements using document.getElementsByName or a similar method, is this possible? Here's my code so far:

```
$('#imagebox img').each(function(){

      var width = $(this).width();
      var height = $(this).height();

        $('<canvas/>', {
        name: 'canv',
        css: {
          margin: '0px',
          background: '#FF0000',
          float: 'left',
          width: width,
          height: height
        }
      }).appendTo('#main'); 

          // Get the canvas element and its drawing context
        var canvas = document.getElementsByName('canv');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        /*
        |---------------------
        | Origin: Top Left
        | End: Bottom Right
        |---------------------
        */

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.stroke();

        /*
        |---------------------
        | Origin: Top Right
        | End: Bottom Left
        |---------------------
        */

        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(canvas.width, 0);
        context.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        context.stroke();
        context.restore();

    });
```

Comment: you mean you want one canvas to effectively appear multiple times on the page, with changes reflected in all copies?

Comment: Yes, the same canvas multiple times with dynamic widths and heights. Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible?

No, it's not possible.

A Canvas element is just like any HTML element - each instance can only appear at most once within the HTML page.

Furthermore, each Canvas has exactly one Context, and Contexts cannot be shared.

Comment: I feared as such! Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible to achieve the effect you desire.

You simply draw onto one of the canvas contexts, and then use `drawImage(originalContext,0,0)` on all the other canvas contexts in order to make a complete copy.

The original canvas (the one that you are doing all the drawing operations on) doesn't even have to be on the page. It could be created just in code if you wanted, and all the ones on the page are just `drawImage`'s of that canvas context.

Here's an exmaple of two canvases "sharing" a context. All the stuff is drawn on canvas1, and then I scale a smaller canvas2 and draw canvas1's context onto it:

http://jsfiddle.net/U6QLN/

Comment: Nice, although technically not a "shared" context.  This is presumably similar to doing getImageData() on the first context and calling putImageData() on the others?

Comment: also, if the source canvas is smaller than the destination canvas you'll get aliasing artefacts as pixels are copied from one to the other.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this also! Interesting stuff. I ended up using an SVG as it was easier to manipulate for my purposes.